# Scala future recursion returning early

Tags: scala, recursion, concurrency

I'm trying to use recursive future calls to get a tree with a certain depth. The Futures.flatMap returns early, but the recursed futures do go on to complete *after* returning early.

We have a graph database with edges (parent-child relationships) and entities (nodes in tree). To retrieve the tree, we have two separate calls: getEdges and getEntitiesFromChildEdges. Both return futures.

The initial call, getEquipment, needs to return a Future. Since I, ultimately, need to return a future, I don't want to add an artificial wait.

Here's the code. `getEquipment` is called first.

```
getTree( rootEntities: Seq[Entity], parents: Seq[Entity], depth: Int): Future[Seq[Entity]] {

  getEdges( parents).flatMap{ edges =>
    getEntitiesFromChildEdges( edges).map{ children =>
      children.foreach{ child => findParent( child).addChild( child) }
      if( depth > 0) {
        getTree( rootEntities, children, depth - 1)
        logTheTree( "DEEPER", rootEntities)
        rootEntities
      } else {
        logTheTree( "!DEEPER", rootEntities)
        rootEntities
      }
    }
  }

}


getEquipment: Future[Json]{

  getRootEntities.flatMap{ rootEntities =>
    getTree( rootEntities, rootEntities, 3).flatMap { returnedRootEntities =>
      logTheTree( "FINAL", rootEntities)
      Json.toJson( rootEntities)
    }
  }

}
```

getEquipment is called first. Here are the log results. Note the logs with `FINAL` return before the tree is completely built.

```
DEEPER Root
DEEPER   One
FINAL Root
FINAL   One
---
DEEPER Root
DEEPER   One
DEEPER     Two
DEEPER     Three
!DEEPER Root
!DEEPER   One
!DEEPER     Two
!DEEPER     Three
```

The tree traversal is breadth-first instead of depth-first to minimize getEntities calls. Not relevant to the question, but does help to understand why the tree traversal is passed a sequence.

Lastly, I know I'm passing in the rootEntities unnecessarily, but the compiler complains when getTree.flatMap doesn't follow with `returnedRootEntities =>`. The actual `getEquipment: Future` is more complicated, but that's for a different question.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/scala/async

Comment: Interesting for other uses, but I don't see how it helps here. It recommends await calls which I don't want to use because my ultimate return is a Future. I can easily update the current function to wrap getEdges with an Await call without the added library dependency.

Comment: instead of 'real-Await', in scala/async await is not blocking operations, and at the end you'll get non-blocking code that returns future

Comment: This is the perfect use for a Promise. Inside the method, before recursing, create a Promise and return the .future from that Promise as the result of the method. Then internally, when you hit the end of the recursing, complete the Promise, thus giving a result to the Future returned to the caller. If you need a quick example, let me know and I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone pointed out that the reason the code was returning early was because the innermost getTree() returns a Future immediately (Doh!). It should have a map and enclose the two lines below it inside the map.

The `else` was changed to Future.successful and the `getEntitiesFromChildEdges( edges).map` was changed to `flatMap`.

Here's the updated code.

```
getTree( rootEntities: Seq[Entity], parents: Seq[Entity], depth: Int): Future[Seq[Entity]] {

  getEdges( parents).flatMap{ edges =>
    getEntitiesFromChildEdges( edges).flatMap{ children =>
      children.foreach{ child => findParent( child).addChild( child) }
      if( depth > 0) {
        // getTree needs to have a map and the results inside it.
        getTree( rootEntities, children, depth - 1).map{ r =>
          logTheTree( "DEEPER", rootEntities)
          rootEntities
        }
      } else {
        logTheTree( "!DEEPER", rootEntities)
        Future.successful( rootEntities)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The answer from cmbaxter show promise :-) I'll look into using that technique in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a example based on my comment of using a `Promise` to handle this `Future` based recursion.  I simplified your example so the code was cleaner, but it still has the same issue of needing to do `Future` based recursion.  Take a look and hopefully you can bridge this into your code:

```
import concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Promise
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import concurrent.duration._

case class Person(id:Long, name:String, children:Option[List[Long]])
object RecurseTest extends App{
  val Everyone = Map(
    1L -> Person(1, "grandpa", Some(List(2,3))),
    2L -> Person(2, "dad", Some(List(4,5))),
    3L -> Person(3, "uncle joe", Some(List(6,7))),
    4L -> Person(4, "me", None),
    5L -> Person(5, "sis", None),
    6L -> Person(6, "cousin fred", None),
    7L -> Person(7, "cousin mary", None)
  )

  val f = getFamilMembers

  //Only using Await here to demonstrate the example.  Do not use in real code
  val result = Await.result(f, 5 seconds)
  println(result)

  def getFamilMembers():Future[List[String]] = {
    var names:List[String] = List.empty
    val prom = Promise[List[String]]
    def recurse(ids:List[Long]){
      ids.headOption match{

        //This is the recursion exit point
        case None => prom.success(names.reverse)
        case Some(id) =>
          getPerson(id) map{ p =>
            names = p.name :: names
            val childIds = p.children.getOrElse(List.empty)
            recurse(ids.tail ++ childIds)
          }                    
      }
    }

    recurse(List(1))  
    prom.future
  }

  def getPerson(id:Long):Future[Person] = {
    Future{         
      val p = Everyone.get(id).get
      println("loaded: " + p.name)
      p
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem with the original code. See the answer below. I never thought of using promises. I'll try using it in the future.